# Date formatting is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following select statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM alerts";
```

I use the following PHP code to echo

```
 echo "" . $row["date"]."";
```

No matter what I do I receive Year-Month-Day instead of Day-Month-Year. 
Any ideas?

Comment: is your variable in mysql of date format?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't alias the formatted date in SQL, so the `date` field from your select is still the same.

Either alias the formatted date and output on that,

```
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS formattedDate FROM alerts";
// ...
echo $row['formattedDate'];
```

Or you can format the date in PHP,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alerts";
// ...
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['formattedDate']));
```